# how to declare output options in sjs file in marklogic

Tags: marklogic, sjs

In XQuery I know the syntax to declare the output options like given below:

```
declare option xdmp:output "method=html";
```

How can I do the same in an SJS module?

Answer (score 2):

`xdmp.setResponseOutputMethod()` should do the equivalent.  See:

http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.setResponseOutputMethod

Hoping that helps,